# How to insert data to Sql DB using EAV model

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-attribute-value

I'm currently creating a project using C#, its a PC store management system. I want to insert data from a windows form to my SQL database, the problem is that I can't figure it out how to manage that. I'm using this model:

```
create table product
(
    part_number int, (PK)
    name varchar(10),
    price int
);

insert into product 
values (1, 'product1', 50),
       (2, 'product2', 95.99);
```

Second the attribute table to store the each of the different attributes.

```
create table attribute
(
     attributeid int, (PK)
     attribute_name varchar(10),
     attribute_value varchar(50)
);

insert into attribute 
values (1, 'color', 'red'),
       (2, 'color', 'blue'),
       (3, 'material', 'chrome'),
       (4, 'material', 'plastic'),
       (5, 'color', 'yellow'),
       (6, 'size', 'x-large');
```

Finally create the `product_attribute` table as the JOIN table between each product and its attributes associated with it.

```
create table product_attribute
(
     part_number int, (FK)
     attributeid int  (FK) 
);

insert into product_attribute 
values (1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 6),
       (2, 2), (2, 6);
```

From this source -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24636/product-attribute-list-design-pattern

And now lets say I have categories like headphones, CPU, monitor, Keyboard.
each category have their own attributes so I think that in this case I need to use EAV model.

How to write my query? Do I always need to check if the attribute is already there, and if it exists so I need to check if the attribute value is same as my current value and only then relate it to my product? And if its not exists I need to create it and then relate it ?

I'm really confused, help me please.

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid (point #3)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) for a discussion of why EAV is really really bad, and see [Bad CaRMa](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292) for a true horror story of an EAV system design that ruined a thriving company.

Comment: To be honest with you its only a project to receive my diploma, so I just need it to be working, do you think I need to create 20 tables for each category and that's it ?

Comment: Breaking data into tables just reduces the size of the database so you do not need to repeat same info on every row.  I would get queries working in SQL Server tools first before trying in c#.  The c# queries (command text) will be the same as in SQL Server.